# Query is too slow (1 second, but needs to improve)

Tags: performance, firebird

I have generated a very large query. Unfortunality this query is too slow for us. The query is 1 second, but it needs to improve too less than a few ms. I don't want duplicates of the result. So I need to put a distinct or something else on it, but this makes it slow. Does anyone knows a good solution for it?

Thank you in advance!

```
SELECT 
"A"."ARTIKEL_ID",
"A"."MUTATOR",
"A"."DATUM_MUT",
"A"."ARTIKEL_NUMMER",
"A"."OMSCHRIJVING",
"A"."ZOEK_TERMEN",
"A"."AANVULLENDE_ARTIKEL_INFORMATIE",
"A"."EENHEID_ID",
"A"."AANTAL_IN_VERPAKKING",
"A"."BTW_SOORT_ID",
"A"."ACTIEF",
"A"."ENTREPOT",
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "KLANT_AANVRAAG_ALTERNATIEF" AS "KAA"
    WHERE "KAA"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyklantaanvraagalternatieven,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "VERKOOP_ORDER_REGEL" AS "VOR"
    WHERE "VOR"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyverkooporderregels,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "ARTIKEL_IMPA" AS "AI"
    WHERE "AI"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyartikelimpas,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "ARTIKEL_ISSA" AS "AI1"
    WHERE "AI1"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyartikelissas,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL" AS "LA"
    WHERE "LA"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyleveranciersartikel,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "VOORRAAD_ARTIKEL" AS "VA"
    WHERE "VA"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyvoorraadartikel
FROM "ARTIKEL" AS "A"
INNER JOIN "LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL" AS "LA1" ON ("LA1"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID")
INNER JOIN "ARTIKEL_IMPA" AS "AI2" ON ("AI2"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID")
INNER JOIN "IMPA" AS "I" ON ("I"."IMPA_ID" = "AI2"."IMPA_ID")
WHERE UPPER( "I"."IMPANUMMER" || "I"."OMSCHRIJVING" ) CONTAINING '100'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
"A"."ARTIKEL_ID",
"A"."MUTATOR",
"A"."DATUM_MUT",
"A"."ARTIKEL_NUMMER",
"A"."OMSCHRIJVING",
"A"."ZOEK_TERMEN",
"A"."AANVULLENDE_ARTIKEL_INFORMATIE",
"A"."EENHEID_ID",
"A"."AANTAL_IN_VERPAKKING",
"A"."BTW_SOORT_ID",
"A"."ACTIEF",
"A"."ENTREPOT",
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "KLANT_AANVRAAG_ALTERNATIEF" AS "KAA"
    WHERE "KAA"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyklantaanvraagalternatieven,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "VERKOOP_ORDER_REGEL" AS "VOR"
    WHERE "VOR"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyverkooporderregels,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "ARTIKEL_IMPA" AS "AI"
    WHERE "AI"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyartikelimpas,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "ARTIKEL_ISSA" AS "AI1"
    WHERE "AI1"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyartikelissas,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL" AS "LA"
    WHERE "LA"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyleveranciersartikel,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "VOORRAAD_ARTIKEL" AS "VA"
    WHERE "VA"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyvoorraadartikel
FROM "ARTIKEL" AS "A"
INNER JOIN "LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL" AS "LA1" ON ("LA1"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID")
INNER JOIN "ARTIKEL_ISSA" AS "AI3" ON ("AI3"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID")
INNER JOIN "ISSA" AS "I1" ON ("I1"."ISSA_ID" = "AI3"."ISSA_ID")
 WHERE UPPER( "I1"."ISSANUMMER" || "I1"."OMSCHRIJVING" ) CONTAINING '100'
 UNION
 SELECT 
"A"."ARTIKEL_ID",
"A"."MUTATOR",
"A"."DATUM_MUT",
"A"."ARTIKEL_NUMMER",
"A"."OMSCHRIJVING",
"A"."ZOEK_TERMEN",
"A"."AANVULLENDE_ARTIKEL_INFORMATIE",
"A"."EENHEID_ID",
"A"."AANTAL_IN_VERPAKKING",
"A"."BTW_SOORT_ID",
"A"."ACTIEF",
"A"."ENTREPOT",
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "KLANT_AANVRAAG_ALTERNATIEF" AS "KAA"
    WHERE "KAA"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyklantaanvraagalternatieven,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "VERKOOP_ORDER_REGEL" AS "VOR"
    WHERE "VOR"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyverkooporderregels,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "ARTIKEL_IMPA" AS "AI"
    WHERE "AI"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyartikelimpas,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "ARTIKEL_ISSA" AS "AI1"
    WHERE "AI1"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyartikelissas,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL" AS "LA"
    WHERE "LA"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyleveranciersartikel,
IIF(EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM "VOORRAAD_ARTIKEL" AS "VA"
    WHERE "VA"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID"), 1, 0) AS anyvoorraadartikel
FROM "ARTIKEL" AS "A"
INNER JOIN "LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL" AS "LA1" ON ("LA1"."ARTIKEL_ID" = "A"."ARTIKEL_ID")
WHERE UPPER( "A"."ARTIKEL_NUMMER" || "A"."OMSCHRIJVING" || "A"."AANVULLENDE_ARTIKEL_INFORMATIE" || "A"."ZOEK_TERMEN" ) CONTAINING '100'
```

Table structure of the database. These are the different tables

[image: Table structure of the database. These are the different tables]

Execution plan:

```
 Field #01: ARTIKEL.ARTIKEL_ID Alias:ARTIKEL_ID Type:INTEGER
 Field #02: ARTIKEL.MUTATOR Alias:MUTATOR Type:STRING(20)
 Field #03: ARTIKEL.DATUM_MUT Alias:DATUM_MUT Type:TIMESTAMP
 Field #04: ARTIKEL.ARTIKEL_NUMMER Alias:ARTIKEL_NUMMER Type:STRING(80)
 Field #05: ARTIKEL.OMSCHRIJVING Alias:OMSCHRIJVING Type:STRING(250)
 Field #06: ARTIKEL.ZOEK_TERMEN Alias:ZOEK_TERMEN Type:STRING(80)
 Field #07: ARTIKEL.AANVULLENDE_ARTIKEL_INFORMATIE       Alias:AANVULLENDE_ARTIKEL_INFORMATIE Type:STRING(250)
 Field #08: ARTIKEL.EENHEID_ID Alias:EENHEID_ID Type:INTEGER
 Field #09: ARTIKEL.AANTAL_IN_VERPAKKING Alias:AANTAL_IN_VERPAKKING Type:NUMERIC(18,3)
 Field #10: ARTIKEL.BTW_SOORT_ID Alias:BTW_SOORT_ID Type:INTEGER
 Field #11: ARTIKEL.ACTIEF Alias:ACTIEF Type:SMALLINT
 Field #12: ARTIKEL.ENTREPOT Alias:ENTREPOT Type:SMALLINT
 Field #13: . Alias:ANYKLANTAANVRAAGALTERNATIEVEN Type:INTEGER
 Field #14: . Alias:ANYVERKOOPORDERREGELS Type:INTEGER
 Field #15: . Alias:ANYARTIKELIMPAS Type:INTEGER
 Field #16: . Alias:ANYARTIKELISSAS Type:INTEGER
 Field #17: . Alias:ANYLEVERANCIERSARTIKEL Type:INTEGER
 Field #18: . Alias:ANYVOORRAADARTIKEL Type:INTEGER
 PLAN (KAA INDEX (AIGEN_FK_KLAAAL_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (VOR INDEX (AIGEN_FK_VEORRE_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (AI INDEX (AIGEN_FK_ARTIMP_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (AI1 INDEX (AIGEN_FK_ARTISS_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (LA INDEX (AIGEN_PK_LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL))
 PLAN (VA INDEX (AIGEN_PK_VOORRAAD_ARTIKEL))
 PLAN (KAA INDEX (AIGEN_FK_KLAAAL_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (VOR INDEX (AIGEN_FK_VEORRE_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (AI INDEX (AIGEN_FK_ARTIMP_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (AI1 INDEX (AIGEN_FK_ARTISS_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (LA INDEX (AIGEN_PK_LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL))
 PLAN (VA INDEX (AIGEN_PK_VOORRAAD_ARTIKEL))
 PLAN (KAA INDEX (AIGEN_FK_KLAAAL_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (VOR INDEX (AIGEN_FK_VEORRE_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (AI INDEX (AIGEN_FK_ARTIMP_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (AI1 INDEX (AIGEN_FK_ARTISS_ARTIID_TO_ARTIK))
 PLAN (LA INDEX (AIGEN_PK_LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL))
 PLAN (VA INDEX (AIGEN_PK_VOORRAAD_ARTIKEL))
 PLAN JOIN (I NATURAL, AI2 INDEX (AIGEN_FK_ARTIIMP_IMPAID_TO_IMPA), A  INDEX (AIGEN_PK_ARTIKEL), LA1 INDEX (AIGEN_PK_LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL))
 PLAN JOIN (AI3 NATURAL, I1 INDEX (AIGEN_PK_ISSA), A INDEX  (AIGEN_PK_ARTIKEL), LA1 INDEX (AIGEN_PK_LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL))
 PLAN JOIN (A NATURAL, LA1 INDEX (AIGEN_PK_LEVERANCIERS_ARTIKEL))
```

Answer (score 4):

Given the information provided, the query itself seems mostly to be correct. That is, it takes time because it is actually checking for a lot of information. The only part of it that looks *improvable* is the `WHERE` conditions:

```
WHERE UPPER( "I1"."ISSANUMMER" || "I1"."OMSCHRIJVING" ) CONTAINING '100'

WHERE UPPER( "A"."ARTIKEL_NUMMER" || "A"."OMSCHRIJVING" ||
        "A"."AANVULLENDE_ARTIKEL_INFORMATIE" || "A"."ZOEK_TERMEN" ) CONTAINING '100'
```

This condition looks like "I am looking for a 100 in either the article number, or the description, or the additional information, or ...". I guess the '100' number is just an example...

1. One thing can easily go wrong:

   ```
   a.artikel_number = '987654321'
   a.omschrijving = '007'
   ```

   ... would meet your condition, and I don't think this is what you're looking for.
2. The database won't be able to use any index to check for these conditions. This looks as if you're trying to look for **words** within several textual columns. If that were the case, you'd most probably would like to use [`FULLTEXT`](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq328/) searches, and use *fulltext indexes*. Firebird doesn't offer (as of now) these facilities built-in. You have them in a number of other databases, such as [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html), [MySQL](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-full-text-search.aspx) (that you don't have to pay for), or [Microsoft SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search) or [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/query.htm#BABGAIHJ), to name a few.
3. If trying to use one of the add-ons for FTS or changing database is out of the question, most probably you would like to have some *computed columns* in your Firebird database:

   ```
   search_column GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
         "ARTIKEL_NUMMER" || ',' || 
         "OMSCHRIJVING" || ',' || 
         "AANVULLENDE_ARTIKEL_INFORMATIE" || ',' ||
         "ZOEK_TERMEN"
   ```

   and index that column.

   This *might* (you'll have to try) slightly help and speedup the `CONTAINING` conditions.

Check also [Improving '% LIKE %' Query on Firebird Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007269/improving-like-query-on-firebird-)